# SSRS date from previous year but with the same weekday name selected

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get last year's date but with the same week day as the one selected.  Meaning that if the user selects Dec 5th 2013 which is a Thursday, the formula would select Dec 6th 2012 which is also a Thursday.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find/Replace "Today()" with the name of the field or parameter.

```
=Switch (
    WeekDay(Today())-WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-365,Today())) = 0, DateAdd("d",-365,Today()),
    WeekDay(Today()) > WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-365,Today())), DateAdd("d",(-365)+ABS(WeekDay(Today())-WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-365,Today()))),Today()),
    WeekDay(Today()) < WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-365,Today())), DateAdd("d",(-365)-ABS(WeekDay(Today())-WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-365,Today()))),Today())
)
```

Comment: Hi Kyzen.  Thanks for your answer.  I found another solution as well.

Comment: =Format(CDate(DateAdd("d", Weekday(Variables!FromDate.Value) - DatePart("w", DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, - 1, Variables!FromDate.Value)), DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, - 1, Variables!FromDate.Value))), "yyyyMMdd")